# how to represent -1 in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

#### Question:

> You are given `eax = 0x1`. Could you set `eax` to zero using only one `add` instruction ?

#### Answer:

```
add %eax, 0xffffffff
```

Why is that ?

Comment: I fail to see a direct link with RE. It's very basic x86 code; first thing I thought was "what an odd way to zero eax".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference:](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html)

> ### Conversion from Two's Complement
>
> Use the number 0xFFFFFFFF as an example. In binary, that is:
>
> `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`
>
> What can we say about this
>   number? It's first (leftmost) bit is 1, which means that this
>   represents a number that is negative. That's just the way that things
>   are in two's complement: a leading 1 means the number is negative, a
>   leading 0 means the number is 0 or positive.
>
> To see what this number is a negative of, we reverse the sign of this
>   number. But how to do that? The class notes say (on 3.17) that to
>   reverse the sign you simply invert the bits (0 goes to 1, and 1 to 0)
>   and add one to the resulting number.
>
> The inversion of that binary number is, obviously:
>
> `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`
>
> Then we add one.
>
> `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`
>
> So the negative of 0xFFFFFFFF is
>   0x00000001, more commonly known as 1. So 0xFFFFFFFF is -1.

Comment: oh, I see! I'm really a newbie on RE, thanks for your help!

Comment: @A.W. no problem. This book will help you: http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/students.html

Comment: ok, I will try fetching the book it sounds nice~ Many thanks! :D

Comment: @SYS_V. The first question you need to ask about `0xFFFFFFFF`, is it a signed or unsigned integer. You assume signed - which may not be valid.

Comment: @fpmurphy1: please explain what result you get when it is *unsigned*. I'd also like to know how a CPU knows if the value stored in a register is signed or unsigned. It's not as if there is a flag stored along, outside the value itself.